# deserializing json , where is column 58?

Tags: json, gson

I am trying to deserialize a json string using gson,
but i keep getting this error
how can i find what is wrong with my json object?
if i put the object through a json validator, it comes back valid

```
   com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 58
com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
```

what do i have to do to find "column 58" inside my json object?

Answer (score 0):

Column 58 should be the 58th character in your JSON string.

If you paste your JSON into a text editor, place your cursor at the beginning and press the right arrow key 58 times and you should end up near it.

Alternatively you can paste your JSON into a decoder such as: http://json.parser.online.fr/

And the error should be indicated to you.